# Creating a flat single relationship in Loopback 3

Tags: mongodb, relationship, loopbackjs, strongloop

Loopback has a way to make a light relationship using `referencesMany` where you can say something like:

```
{
    "name": "SomeModel",
    "plural": "SomeModel",
    // ...,
    "relations": {
      "images": {
          "type": "referencesMany",
          "model": "Images",
          "options": {
            "validate": true
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Which will allow you to store an array of `ObjectId` in MongoDB.

I can then do something like:

`SomeModel.find({ include: 'images' })` or `GET` to `/api/SomeModel/?filter[include]=images` to include a response with nested image objects that are related to the `SomeModel`.

Is there a good way to do this in a singular case (not an array of values)? Relate one parent to a child? `HasOne` puts a `someModelId` on the child and I don't really want to pollute the `Image` model with `BelongsTo` as its polymorphic and belongs to all sorts of stuff.